# Namenode uptime metric Ambari server

Tags: azure-hdinsight, ambari

I have a spark cluster running on HDInsights. Ambari shows some general metrics in its dashboard, such as *Namenode uptime*. Where/How may I find the raw data related to such metric?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "**Enable HDInsight Azure Monitor logs integration**" to find the raw data related to any metrics that are available in Ambari UI.

**[Using Ambari Dashboard:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster-availability)**

Ambari dashboard, which contains widgets that show a handful of metrics to give you a quick overview of your HDInsight cluster's health. These widgets show metrics such as the number of live DataNodes (worker nodes) and JournalNodes (zookeeper node), NameNodes (head nodes) **uptime**, as well metrics specific to certain cluster types, like YARN ResourceManager uptime for Spark and Hadoop clusters.

[image]

**[Using Azure Monitor:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/cluster-availability-monitor-logs)**

Azure Monitor logs enable data generated by multiple resources, such as HDInsight clusters, to be collected and aggregated in one place to achieve a unified monitoring experience.

> As a prerequisite, you'll need a Log Analytics Workspace to store the collected data. If you haven't already created one, you can follow instructions here: [Create a Log Analytics Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace).

HDInsight clusters include Azure Monitor logs integration, which provides queryable metrics and logs, as well as configurable alerts. This article shows [how to use Azure Monitor to monitor your cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/cluster-availability-monitor-logs).

As an example, run the **Availability rate** sample query by selecting Run on that query, as shown in the screenshot above. This will show the availability rate of each node in your cluster as a percentage. If you have enabled multiple HDInsight clusters to send metrics to the same Log Analytics workspace, you'll see the availability rate for all nodes in those clusters displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Ambari agent is likely using `os.system()`  python calls. You can do the same with

`ssh user@node -c "uptime"`